# how do I pull my git user mail user and password to send email from my local repository?

Tags: python, git

How can I pull git users email login info from my git local repository using python to send email  with my custom git command ?

I want to do something like `git send-email` does, it sends email without asking for password.

Answer (score 0):

you can get email by doing something like this:

```
with open('.gitconfig') as f:
    text=f.readlines()
for line in text:
    if 'email' in line:
        print line[line.index('=')+2:]
```

`git send-email` should work without passwords provided you have the `ssh` keys

Comment: How to take advantage of `ssh` keys for authentication then?